# respondsToSelector can not recognise the implemented selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a simple subclass of UIViewController I just implemented a selector as a callback to refresh UI

```
-(void)afterfollowAction:(id)object{
  //blabla
}
```

but finally I found respondsToSelector can not recognise it. Test code:

```
SEL callback = @selector(afterFollowAction:);
BOOL test1 = [self respondsToSelector:callback]; //NO
BOOL test2 = [self respondsToSelector:@selector(afterFollowAction:)]; //NO
BOOL test3 = [[self class] instanceMethodForSelector: @selector(afterFollowAction:)];  //YES
BOOL test4 = [self respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWillDisappear:)]; //YES
[self performSelector:callback withObject:nil]; //crash
```

test2 shows not the local variable callback's issue,

test4 shows it knows it is a UIViewController and self is not nil

test3 shows actually it knows the selector is implemented

but if you invoke it with "performSelector" it throw exception "unrecognized selector"

I searched the web and I did not make error with ":" or nil thing;

I put the declaration of the selector to the header file, but makes no use.

I restarted the Mac and iPhone but it is the same result.

This is a simple class in which I do not re-implement respondsToSelector: selector.

So, Did I make wrong use of respondsToSelector? I just want to make the callback outside this class.

Environment:  Mac OS X 10.11.3, Xcode 7.2.1, iOS 9.2.1

Update: find(cmd+F) without match case hide the f/F issue. Thanks to Kiran!

Comment: Did you added the function declaration to .h file as well ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
SEL callback = @selector(afterfollowAction:);
BOOL test1 = [self respondsToSelector:callback]; //NO
BOOL test2 = [self respondsToSelector:@selector(afterfollowAction:)]; //NO
BOOL test3 = [[self class] instanceMethodForSelector: @selector(afterfollowAction:)];  //YES
BOOL test4 = [self respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWillDisappear:)]; //YES
[self performSelector:callback withObject:nil]; //crash
```

Your are using capital "F"

Comment: Thanks very much! and Fxxk myself! When I wrote down this question, I even wanted to emphasise that I used copy/paste and cmd+F to check! Finally my stupid!

Comment: use cmd+f with case sensitivity :)